# How to add multiple term aggregation to search request?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How can I add multiple term independent aggregation to `elasticsearch` `searchRequest` in Java?

Right now I am doing it in cycle for a single field at the time and combining the answers but this is inefficient.

Is there any better way how can I combine multiple independent term aggregation into one search request ?

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: @syntagma Right now I am doing it in cycle for every field I am interested. Then I am connecting it to final response, but this is not really good solution since I am making unnecessary calls to elastic.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Specifically, you need to edit your question to show what you have already tried.